# How to create a seperate class tab for a pie chart in processing?

Tags: processing

I want to add a pie chart to my project but I want to be able to have a class tab just for the coding for the pie chart, and in setup() draw() tab just have code to output the pie chart. I want to be able to make the setup() draw() coding window look cleaner as that it is assessed in my project.
Below I am providing my original code and then what I tried to do to make a separate class tab for the pie chart's code.

The error that I am getting is 'The constructor "PieChart(int, int, int, int[], int[])" does not exist" in line 8 of setup() draw() tab and 'Return type for the method is missing' in line 7 of PieChart tab.

Original code:

```
int[] values = {32, 11, 7};
int[] colors = {#E4000F, #655CBE, #107C10};

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  pixelDensity(2); 
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  background(25);
  pieChart(width/2, height/2, 200, values, colors);
}

// pX, pY : position
// pRad : diameter
// pVal: Array of Values
// pCols: Array of colors

void pieChart(float pX, float pY, float pDia, int[] pVal, int[]pCols) {
  stroke(225);
  float total = 0;
  float lastAngle= -PI;
  float mouseAngle = atan2(mouseY-pY, mouseX-pX);

  // get sum of values
  for (int i =0; i<pVal.length; i++) {
    total += pVal[i];
  }

  for (int i =0; i<pVal.length; i++) {
    fill(pCols[i]);
    float angle = map(pVal[i], 0, total, 0, 2*PI);
    arc(pX, pY, pDia, pDia, lastAngle, lastAngle+angle, PIE);

    if ( mouseAngle >= lastAngle && mouseAngle < lastAngle+angle ) {
      text(values[i] + "/50", pX-pDia/2, pY-pDia/2);
    }

    lastAngle += angle;
  }
}
```

Attempt at making a separate class code (setup() draw() tab):

```
int[] values = {32, 11, 7};
int[] colors = {#E4000F, #655CBE, #107C10};

PieChart pieChart;

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  pieChart = new PieChart(width/2, height/2, 200, values, colors);
}

void draw() {
  background(25);
}
```

Attempt at making a separate class code (PieChart tab):

```
class PieChart {
  //pX, pY : position
  // pRad : diameter
  // pVal: Array of Values
  // pCols: Array of colors

  pieChart(float pX, float pY, float pDia, int[] pVal, int[]pCols) {
    noStroke();
    float total = 0;
    float lastAngle= -PI;
    float mouseAngle = atan2(mouseY-pY, mouseX-pX);


    // get sum of values
    for (int i =0; i<pVal.length; i++) {
      total += pVal[i];
    }

    for (int i =0; i<pVal.length; i++) {
      fill(pCols[i]);
      float angle = map(pVal[i], 0, total, 0, 2*PI);
      arc(pX, pY, pDia, pDia, lastAngle, lastAngle+angle, PIE);

      if ( mouseAngle >= lastAngle && mouseAngle < lastAngle+angle ) {
        text(values[i] + "/50)", pX-pDia/2, pY-pDia/2);
      }
      lastAngle += angle;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Shoudn't the constructor have the same name and capitalization than the class? I mean:  `pieChart(float pX, float pY, float pDia, int[] pVal, int[]pCols) {...}`  shouldn't  be `PieChart(float pX, float pY, float pDia, int[] pVal, int[]pCols) {...}` with a capita P?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following runs in Java on my system:

```
int[] values = {32, 11, 7};
int[] colors = {#E4000F, #655CBE, #107C10};

class PieChart {

void pieChart(float pX, float pY, float pDia, int[] pVal, int[]pCols) {
    noStroke();
    float total = 0;
    float lastAngle= -PI;
    float mouseAngle = atan2(mouseY-pY, mouseX-pX);

    // get sum of values
    for (int i =0; i<pVal.length; i++) {
      total += pVal[i];
    }

    for (int i =0; i<pVal.length; i++) {
      fill(pCols[i]);
      float angle = map(pVal[i], 0, total, 0, 2*PI);
      arc(pX, pY, pDia, pDia, lastAngle, lastAngle+angle, PIE);

      if ( mouseAngle >= lastAngle && mouseAngle < lastAngle+angle ) {
        text(values[i] + "/50)", pX-pDia/2, pY-pDia/2);
      }
      lastAngle += angle;
    }
  }
}

PieChart pieChart;

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  pixelDensity(2); 
  smooth();
  pieChart = new PieChart();
}

void draw() {
  background(25);
  pieChart.pieChart(width/2.0, height/2.0, 200.0, values, colors);
}
```